# Why is part of my model acting wierd?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I am working on a spiderman fan film and noticed that my model had weirdly shaped arms, what tools can I use to fix this?[image]

Comment: The bone weights are wrong, you can repaint them in weight paint mode.

Comment: ive tried that. but it seems to not want to paint in that area